# Sharelatex storage question

Tags: sharelatex

Overleaf has a inital free storage size, which can be upgraded with the pro version or with referrals. What is the storage size of Sharelatex, as I did not find any information on that.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Did you have any luck with their support? Like customer service? I think this is a more appropriate question for their CS.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> There is no limit on the total size of a project, however

from [Limitations on Uploads](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Uploading_a_project)